# Swing listen for child layout changes

Tags: java, swing, layout

I have a JPanel and when its layout changes, I need to re-layout the parent. This can easily be done with panel.getParent().validate(), but the problem is, I don't always know if its direct parent, or maybe some parent somewhere in the tree is really the one that needs to be validated. Is there a way for a parent component to listen to see when its child component is re-layed out so the parent can then relay itself out.

edit: clarification

In my case, the parent has some extra components that need to be relayed out when the child changes, but this isn't always the case. The same child could be use on another parent where the parent doesn't need to be relayed out, so I want to let the parent decide if/when it should relay itself out.

```
// this layoutChangedListener is what I'm trying to accomplish
child.addLayoutChangedListener(new LayoutChangedListener() {
    public void layoutChanged() {
      parent.validate();
    }
});
```

thanks,

Jeff

Comment: Could you give a short example on how can a child be re-layed out without the parent being involved? I don't get it.

Comment: Sorry my post was a little unclear. I know the parent needs to be involved, but basically I want to revalidate the parent whenever the child layout changes (or relayout the parent of the parent). I've added some sample code that might help clear up when I'm trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: That is not sample code, that is a sample solution. Where is the SSCCE that demonstrates the problem. If you don't know what a SSCCE is then search the web

Comment: Can you add component listener to a child for a size or move event? you would have to do some checking not to get caught in a loop.

Comment: Hmm...I could look to see what component events are available. That might work, thanks.

Comment: hard without sample... but shouldn't `revalidate()` do the job?

Answer (score 0):

You can `implements LayoutChangedListener` in your parent class and when you initialize the child you should add the parent as listener. In this way you only must call the validate function.

A little example:

```
class Parent extends JPanel implements LayoutChangedListener {
    //Your class code
    ...
    // The LayoutChangedListener function
    public void layoutChanged() {
        validate();
    }
}
```

You also must change `the child.addLayoutListener()` line. The new one must be as follows:
`child.addLayoutListener(this)`

Possibly this is not the prettiest way, but it works!

Regards!